# How to monitor slow PHP processes?

Tags: performance, logging, php

I run PHP-FPM with Nginx. I have a variety of different scripts on my servers. Sometimes, there's a problem with PHP codes and the process takes too long. This consumes all available PHP-FPM childs; thus, hinders other php scripts.

How can I set the PHP-FPM log to record slow php processes, as we monitor slow mysql queries, to detect which script is causing problem?

Comment: try Pinba: http://pinba.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: @OZ_  That looks helpful, you should post as an answer.

Comment: I wrote a PHP web app that benchmarks the best known current logging frameworks for PHP (error_log, KLogger, Log4php, Monolog), in case it helps anyone: https://github.com/jorgeorpinel/php-logging-benchmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set the PHP-FPM log

No. Use the [nginx log_format](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule) to record the duration of each HTTP request with millisecond accuracy.

> as we monitor slow mysql queries

So you're already stripping out literal values and prioritizing based on the product of frequency and elapsed time?

Comment: Very subtle idea to use the power of web server to do so. Actually, I thought that there might be a feature for php-fpm log that I missed. Instead of using an additional monitoring system, I prefer to use the native webserver.

Answer (score 7):

php-fpm support slow logging feature of php script

in your php-fpm.conf you need to add 2 variable

request_slowlog_timeout and slowlog

according to php-fpm wiki

; The timeout for serving a single request after which a PHP backtrace will be
; dumped to the 'slowlog' file. A value of '0s' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0

```
request_slowlog_timeout = 30
```

; The log file for slow requests
; Default Value: not set
; Note: slowlog is mandatory if request_slowlog_timeout is set

```
slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow
```

to monitor mysql queries i am using this query to get the list of queries that are being run on my machine

```
show full processlist;
```

Comment: MySQL has long had an option to log slow queries - previously a value of '0' meant disable the log file - but the developers realised it was important to be able to log the response times for *all* queries in order to understand perofmrance problems. If you spend some time working with performance issuse, the reasons for this are rather obvious. In PHP-FPM, a value of 0 disables the functionality. And given the behaviour of this option, it should be used as a last ditch attempt to deal with por perfomrance - not the first thing to try.

Answer (score 4):

This is the second time today when I get to recommend [RPM](http://newrelic.com)

This is an application performance monitoring tool. Initially, it was a killer app for Rails, but later they started supporting PHP.

It can monitor your scripts, track slow ones, display all kinds of charts.

It also takes care of slow SQL (and you can even see explain plans from within the tool!)

You should definitely check it out.

Comment: Quite nice, but I tend to avoid  monthly licensing fees. For $0 and a couple of lines of code, I feel custom solution has an edge on flexibility. With a few lines of custom code, you can profile whatever scripts, back-end or front-end, linux or windows, localhost or production server.  Most profiling I do, flash animated charts of my scripts function calls is overkill.

Comment: Well, it all depends, of course. If you're hosting your home page, it's fine to roll your own solution and have fun in the process. But if you're trying to run a business, you probably don't want to spend time and money on what's been already well implemented. It's all about costs and profits.

Comment: Exactly. Costs and profits. Most clients I work for are medium sized or small companies, and the admins usually go for keeping monthly operation costs to a minimum.   [cacti](http://munin-monitoring.org/) and [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) are 2 *free*  monitoring solutions I have used before with good results, but found over time to be overkill. 3 lines of code, and you can profile anything.  Speed, efficiency and flexibility to use and reuse anywhere, free. I don't want to imply it's not a good application you posted, just that some people like graphs (+ paid support), some don't.

Comment: I am going to slightly disagree with you here. 3 lines of code is enough to put a piece of code under stopwatch. But then you have to store these benchmark results somewhere, manage that DB, build your own admin page with charts, etc. "3 lines of code" is quite an oversimplification.

Comment: I will concede that my 3 lines of code do not store data, they are more profiling and benchmarking utils. And I did oversimplify a touch, because it is actually 7 lines. ;) And hey, I did bookmark that app you posted! Good-day my friend

Comment: I don't mean to appear as trying to sell that tool. I was just trying to say that for a small monthly fee it provides constant monitoring with pretty animated charts :-) What if your site shows up on digg or slashdot or whatever, and (suddenly) is hardly breathing. This is not the best time to change production code, adding benchmarks in places where you never did before. But then again, it's one's choice.

Comment: @stefgosselin good day to you too! May the source be with you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this class](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark) to profile and moniter my own utility scripts. It works fine, if you have nothing against Pear classes.

You can set different timers in the code and act upon the values those timers return. As a bonus, you can have a text or html profiling output of how long it takes for each timer to run.

[See the docs for more info](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark/docs/latest/Benchmark/Benchmark_Timer.html).

Hope that helps,  good-luck.

Answer (score 1):

[Appgati](http://fotuzlab.github.io/appgati/) might be of some help here.

It is not an out-an-out solution to your problem, but can provide some useful insights into where the lag has been introduced. You might be having data loss, or losing time in generating the DOM. This script gives sky view of potential areas of concern which can then be specifically targeted.

It can also come handy in finding the performance of a particular function in the script.

**Sample output:**

```
Array
(
[Clock time in seconds] => 1.9502429962158
[Time taken in User Mode in seconds] => 0.632039
[Time taken in System Mode in seconds] => 0.024001
[Total time taken in Kernel in seconds] => 0.65604
[Memory limit in MB] => 128
[Memory usage in MB] => 18.237907409668
[Peak memory usage in MB] => 19.579357147217
[Average server load in last minute] => 0.47
[Maximum resident shared size in KB] => 44900
[Integral shared memory size] => 0
[Integral unshared data size] => 0
[Integral unshared stack size] => 
[Number of page reclaims] => 12102
[Number of page faults] => 6
[Number of block input operations] => 192
[Number of block output operations] => 
[Number of messages sent] => 0
[Number of messages received] => 0
[Number of signals received] => 0
[Number of voluntary context switches] => 606
[Number of involuntary context switches] => 99
```

)

Comment: interesting thing! nice to know it.